# Android Testing Data propagation across multiple applications

Tags: android, android-testing

I have data that I share across multiple applications.  The data can be pushed from any of our applications.

I am trying to see if there is a tool where I can perform actions across more than one applications and then check that the data in our database file after some time and can recover after application crashes.

Has anyone had any luck with this?  One approach I am thinking is to modify the Robotium configuration by swapping out files and running but this seems hacky.

Comment: I am not sure about what kind of data you want to share, but in our application we saved credentials in sharedPreference, and accessed it across applications. Elaborate about the data you wish to share, lets see what we find out.

Comment: credential data is one of the items.  Currently our storage is backed by an sqlite database.  When you say you access sharedPrefs across apps, do you expose via a content provider or mark the sharedPrefs as world readable/writable.  If the latter, is there a way to make sure not all applications on the device cannot read?

Comment: we used later one.. used android:sharedUserId so that only applications having same sharedUserID can use it.

Comment: and i have set its mode to private + and used shareduserID.

Comment: ahh I see .. that sounds like a good solution but some of the apps are already shipped so we cannot change the sharedUserId.